# Как вставить блок, посреди каталога вукомерс?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, while

[image: Как вставить такой блок]

Как вставить блок, посреди каталога вукомерс? Сейчас код шаблона каталога выглядит вот так.

```
 <div class="catalog-shop shop">
                        <div class="row">


        <?php
        if (woocommerce_product_loop()) {

            /**
             * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop.
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_output_all_notices - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
             * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
             */
            //do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );

            //woocommerce_product_loop_start();

            if (wc_get_loop_prop('total')) {
                while (have_posts()) {
                    the_post();

                    /**
                     * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop.
                     */
                    do_action('woocommerce_shop_loop');

                    wc_get_template_part('content', 'product');
                }
            }

            woocommerce_product_loop_end();

            ?>



            <?php
        } else {
            /**
             * Hook: woocommerce_no_products_found.
             *
             * @hooked wc_no_products_found - 10
             */
            do_action('woocommerce_no_products_found');
        }

        /**
         * Hook: woocommerce_after_main_content.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
         */
        //do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );


        ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте такой код в `functions.php` вашей темы:

```
function my_woocommerce_shop_loop() {
    static $product_counter = 0;

    $insert_after = 6;

    if ( $product_counter === $insert_after ) {
        // Output my block here.
        ?>
        <div></div>
        <?php
    }

    $product_counter ++;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop', 'my_woocommerce_shop_loop' );
```

Исправьте 6 на число товаров, после которых надо вывести ваш блок. Добавьте код блока в `<div></div>`.

Comment: Класс. Работает. спасибо большое